# slime startup in emacs in a splitter windows buffer, how to make it a full window?

Tags: emacs, elisp, slime

Here is my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Documents/slime/")  ; your SLIME directory
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/bin/sbcl") ; your Lisp system
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-asdf slime-banner))
(slime)
```

Everytime i start emacs, slime started in a split window. 
How to make it start in a full window?

Comment: The first question is what buffer is displayed in the other window (?), and that will tell us part of what we need to know.  The second and perhaps the most likely possibility is that your slime setup has a `display-buffer` or `pop-to-buffer` or something similar in its calling, which could be splitting the window.  And, as you've already seen, you can just fix it after it happens with `delete-other-windows`.  It's not bad to `delete-other-windows`, but eventually you may be interested in tracking down the root cause and have it displayed in a full window at the outset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your slime.el or .emacs

```
(setq pop-up-windows nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you call `(slime)`

```
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook #'delete-other-windows)
```

Comment: add the following works: 
    (add-hook 'slime-connected-hook 'delete-other-windows)
but it shows a splitter windows first, then become a full window.